# Vector as the sum of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering how to compose the vector $(-2, 3, 1)$ as the sum of the vectors $(1, -2, 0)$, $(0, -2, 2)$, and $(-1, 1, 1)$, and if there is a method to determine the linear independence of the same vectors.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Do you know how to solve a system of linear equations in 3 variables?

Comment: If you do know about that, have you tried using it to solve this? How? Or did you use something else? Please put it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write $(-2,3,1)=a(1,-2,0)+b(0,2,2)+c(-1,1,1)$, and solve for $a,b,c$. There are various ways to check whether your vectors are linearly independent. One way is to check that the determinant of the matrix $M=(v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})$ is non-zero for your three vectors. If it is, your vectors are linearly independent. If not, they are linearly dependent. Another way is to check that the only solution to $a(1,-2,0)+b(0,2,2)+c(-1,1,1)=(0,0,0)$ is $a=b=c=0$. If this holds, your vectors are linearly independent. Otherwise, they are linearly dependent.

Comment: after solving for a, b,c in (−2,3,1)=a(1,−2,0)+b(0,-2,2)+c(−1,1,1), i get an infinte amount of solutions. What would be the answer vector in that case?

Comment: @ueou...the three vector are linearly independent, so this equation has a unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

All problems of this kind reduce to solving a system of linear equations. If your basis vectors are $(a_1,a_2,a_3),(b_1,b_2,b_3),(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ and you want to represent $(d_1,d_2,d_3)$ as a linear combination of those, let the coefficients you're looking for be x,y,z. The problem reduces to solving $$a_1x+a_2y+a_3z=d_1,b_1x+b_2y+b_3z=d_2,c_1x+c_2y+c_3z=d_3$$. Also if you want to check for linear dependence to the first three vectors and set $(d_1,d_2,d_3)=(0,0,0)$ and solve for $x,y,z$. If they come out to be zero you have linear independence otherwise...

Comment: what if in solving for x,y,z there is an infinte amount of solutions, would choosing one combination of x,y,z be correct?

Comment: If there are infinite number of solutions it means your basis vectors are not linearly independent. Yes choosing one would suffice...

Answer (score 0):

**Just Expounding...**(on Edward's post)
$$(−2,3,1)=a(1,−2,0)+b(0,-2,2)+c(−1,1,1)$$

So therefore grouping each constant on the left-hand side with the respective variable and its coefficient on the right-hand side, you'll end up with:

$$-2=a-c\\
3=-2a-2b+c\\
1=2b+c$$
And then you solve for the variables $a,\space b,\text{and}\space c$ to prove that since $(1,−2,0), (0,-2,2), (−1,1,1)$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $(-2,3,1)$ that the three vectors are linearly dependent.

You can determine if vectors are linearly independent/dependent by calculating the determinant or by solving the system of equations that the vectors make up.

1. If the *determinant* is $0$, the vectors are **linearly dependent**. If the *determinant* is **non-zero**, then the vectors are **linearly independent**. 
   $$
           \begin{vmatrix}
           1 & -2 & 0 \\
           0 & -2 & 2 \\
           -1 & 1 & 1 \\
           \end{vmatrix}=0
   $$
   Since the determinant is $0$, clearly the three vectors are linearly dependent.
2. If the system has a *unique solution* then the vectors are **linearly independent**. If the system is *inconsistent* or has an *infinite number of solutions* then it is **linearly dependent**.